# Pressing PrintScreen to take a screenshot closes all open applications

Tags: 18.10, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

On Ubuntu 18.10, when I use gnome-screenshot and press <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, the window log out automatically and close all apps. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the shortcuts **Logout** and **Shutdown** in **System Settings** and navigate to **Devices** -> **keyboard**.

In right, scroll down and find out these key. Change for appropriate keys.

Comment: i can found this setting, only suspend for turn on and turn of, also i see the screenshot filr on ./Pictures but its broken file, cant see using third party apps too, i try on windows too, but still cant open the file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's bug of gnome-shell.

ref: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/1017

For workaround is just change 'Format' in **Settings -> Region & Language** to any format that **Dates & Times** is not blank.

In my case, I changes to UK.